# Tracking progress, learning management system, Ruby on Rails 4, architecture issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently building a learning management system with rails 4, I am   Trying to improve my skills. I cannot figure out how to implement the following iteration.

Each student has many courses, each course has many lessons, therefore each student has many lessons through course

Models: 
User
Course
Lessons

What I am trying to do is to implement a tracking progress system so that when a user finish watching a video he clicks on go to the next video and then it is possible to see the progress on their profile page.

Any advise on how I should implement it? The tracking progress is real pain for me and I have no clue on how to do it! Sorry if I am not clear enough. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: How does a "Video" relate to a "Lesson"?  Are they the same thing?  Does a lesson have many videos?

Comment: A lesson has one video. A lesson has a title, content and video. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should draw out a simple UML diagram for classes, based on real world entities, and how they relate.    Start out by making sure you have all the classes to model the actual structure of the course.  Is "Course" and "Lesson" actually enough for this?  Is it that simple?

Then, add new classes to track the progress of users.  I would prefix all of these class names with the same word, like "viewed".  This is about as simple as it could be (probably too simple i suspect).  I am assuming that a lesson contains a video so when they've watched the video they've completed the lesson.  It may not be as simple as that but you don't specify any other requirements (eg coursework).

```
class Course
  has_many :lessons

class Lesson
  #fields: course_id
  belongs_to :course

class User
  has_many :viewed_lessons
  has_many :viewed_courses

class ViewedLesson
  #fields: user_id, lesson_id, completed(boolean)  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson

class ViewedCourse
  #fields: user_id, course_id, completed(boolean)  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
```

When a user signs up to a course you make a viewed_course record for them.  You can work out which lesson is next for them by looking for the first lesson where there isn't a viewed_lesson for that lesson and user which is marked as completed.

When they finish the video you mark the corresponding lesson as completed, which means that the above logic will suggest the next video.  When all lessons in a course are completed you can mark the viewed_course as completed too.

Comment: Thank you max, each lessons has only one video, I am working on something basic. Thank you for you clear explanation.

Comment: Cool.  Just remember to "keep it real", ie try to make your application schema match the common sense real world as much as possible.